# unable to add multiple users in Jmeter - tried with CSV still failing

Tags: python, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I have CSV file  with added in the CSV Data Set Config,

[please click the url to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8S8zd.jpg)

CSV file content

```
EMAIL,USERNAME,FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,PASSWORD
pfuser2@pfuser.com,pfuser2,PF,User,test1234
pfuser3@pfuser.com,pfuser3,PF,User,test1234
pfuser4@pfuser.com,pfuser4,PF,User,testt1234
pfuser5@pfuser.com,pfuser5,PF,User,testt1234
```

passing the above values to post request as below

[click the link to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ph3AD.jpg)

the request data is simply passed has parameter names ,instead of values  please see the below sample request

```
email=%24%28EMAIL%29&user_name=%24%28USERNAME%29&first_name=%24%28FIRSTNAME%29&last_name=%24%28LASTNAME%29&password=%24%28PASSWORD%29
```

Comment: remove the first row from the CSV file and then pass it.

Comment: still same issue, no luck POST data:
email=%24%28EMAIL%29&user_name=%24%28USERNAME%29&first_name=%24%28FIRSTNAME%29&last_name=%24%28LASTNAME%29&password=%24%28PASSWORD%29

Answer (score 0):

- Either set `Ignore first line` to `True`

  [image]
- or set it to `False` and remove everything from the "Variable Names" section, this way JMeter will use the values from "headings" as the variable names.

You can see all [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) with their respective values using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) listener combination.

Also it worth checking [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for any suspicious entries.

Comment: still same :( no luck